# How to remove GRUB 2.0 and Mint(15) AND restore the Windows 8 boot GUI?

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub, linux-mint

The bottom line is that I have no use for Mint Linux anymore, and would like to remove grub along with the OS. 
The problem is that I finally have Windows 8 set up just that special little way I like it! 
I've done my fair share of research and have found that, between Windows XP and Windows 7, the commands vary between the operating systems. I'm afraid to try any commands related to older operating systems due to this fact.

I do happen to have the installation disc as well as my serial and a repair disc at disposal.
I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I do have a picture of how my drives are partitioned here: http://puu.sh/3O5wC.png
I'm using a GPT table instead of MBR, I think, so please keep that in mind.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alright, well, I spent about six hours backing up my drives and the Windows 7 tutorial from here: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub Just use the Windows 8 instllation disc instead. Seeing as I can't answer my own question, I hope somebody just copies and pastes this into the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page while searching for other thing and I don't know if you still need the answer. Anyway, here's what you need to do:

1. You should make sure that the boot partition for windows 8 is marked as "Active". To do this, open "Computer Management -> Disk Management". Look for the a partition marked as "System" and make sure it has the "Active" flag as well. If not, right click it and select "Mark partition as active".
2. Now if GRUB was installed on the same "System" marked partition you need to clean it up. For doing this you need a utility like EasyBCD (get it free from [here](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)). Download, install, and Run it.
3. From "EasyBCD Toolbox" select "BCD Backup/Repair".
4. From "BCD Management Options" select "Reset BCD configuration" then click "Perform Action". Once done, select "Re-create/repair boot files" and again click "Perform Action".
5. From "EasyBCD Toolbox" select "Add New Entry".
6. In "Operating Systems" Type "Windows 8" inside "Name" filed [Optional] then click "Add Entry".
7. From "EasyBCD Toolbox" select "Edit Boot Menu" then select "Skip the boot menu" from "Timeout Options" and click "Save Settings".

That's it!